# Pagebreak and Verbatim environments

Tags: page-breaking, verbatim

Given the following [piece of code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64493/how-to-set-the-top-margin-for-a-custom-verbatim-environment-fancyvrb):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{shell}{Verbatim}{
  commandchars=\%\{\},
  label=\shelltitle,
  frame=single,
  samepage=true,
  formatcom=\setcounter{prompt}{0}\start
}
\newcommand{\shelltitle}{This is a shell}

\makeatletter
\def\start{\let\FV@FV@ProcessLine\FV@ProcessLine
  \def\FV@ProcessLine{\noindent\vrule height3ex depth2ex 
                      \hbox to\hsize{\kern\FV@FrameSep This is the shell prompt\hfil}%
                      \kern-.8pt\vrule\par
                      \let\FV@ProcessLine\FV@FV@ProcessLine
                      \FV@ProcessLine}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{prompt}
\newcommand{\prompt}{\stepcounter{prompt}\theprompt>}

\begin{document}
\begin{shell}
%prompt echo foo{}
foo
%prompt echo bar
bar
\end{shell}
\end{document}
```

The `samepage=true` option doesn't affect the heading line ("This is the shell prompt") and page break happens immediately after that line. How can I ensure the heading line resides on the same page of the rest of the listing?

Comment: Did you try adding `\nobreak` just after `\kern-.8pt\vrule\par`?

Answer (score 3):

As egreg mentioned in his comment, is enough to use `\nobreak` right after `\kern-.8pt\vrule\par`. In the following example, if you delete the `\nobreak` command and process the resulting code, you'll see the undesired effect mentioned (a page break right after the line "This is the shell prompt"); processing the document as it is (with `\nobreak`) you'll see that the page break inside the environment is suppressed and the whole text is moved to the second page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{shell}{Verbatim}{
  commandchars=\%\{\},
  label=\shelltitle,
  frame=single,
  samepage=true,
  formatcom=\setcounter{prompt}{0}\start
}
\newcommand{\shelltitle}{This is a shell}

\makeatletter
\def\start{\let\FV@FV@ProcessLine\FV@ProcessLine
  \def\FV@ProcessLine{\noindent\vrule height3ex depth2ex 
                      \hbox to\hsize{\kern\FV@FrameSep This is the shell prompt\hfil}%
                      \kern-.8pt\vrule\par\nobreak
                      \let\FV@ProcessLine\FV@FV@ProcessLine
                      \FV@ProcessLine}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{prompt}
\newcommand{\prompt}{\stepcounter{prompt}\theprompt>}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{18cm}
\begin{shell}
%prompt echo foo{}
foo
%prompt echo bar
bar
\end{shell}
\end{document}
```